# Get Android device token

Tags: android, pushwoosh, devicetoken, android-devicetoken

I am integrating `Pushwoosh` API for push notifications for which I require **deviceToken**. How do I get it :

I am getting empty string using this :

```
String deviceToken=GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
```

These are the permissions I have in my **AndroidMainfest.xml** :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application ...>
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```

Is this the right way to get **deviceToken**.

Comment: can you pl confirm , you have given internet permission in your manifest or your internet is accessible to your device or not

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia : Yes I have.

Comment: if possible can you pl provide code so better to understand where you have problem

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia : This is the single line of code I am using for getting deviceToken. Nothing else. Mainfest premissions are same as Ashish has mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking fine, just compare your AndroidManifest with below code to make sure you are not missing anything there -

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application ...>
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't have GcmIntentService anywhere in application. I am using the default GcmBroadcastReceiver. With that matter ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, hope it will help you

```
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(getApplicationContext());
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(getApplicationContext());    

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```